# Django DRF nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF and trying to write a prototype of API for storing rectangle labels on a photo.
my models:

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)

class Label(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_x = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    start_y = models.IntegerFIeld(default=0)
    end_x = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    end_y = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

my serializers:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class LabelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Label
        fields = ['id', 'image', 'start_x', 'start_y', 'end_x', 'end_y']

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    labels = LabelSerializer(many=True, read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['id', 'file', 'labels']
```

When creating new image object in the following view I get image object, but no Labels objects created :

```py
from .serializers import ImageSerializer

class ImageView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ImageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            response_data = {'id': serializer.data['id']}
            return Response(response_data,
                                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

API call:
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@~/test.jpg" --form-string 'labels={[{"start_x": 0, "start_y": 0, "end_x": 100, "end_y": 200}]}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/

How should I modify ImageSerializer for making possible to create image with labels with one API call?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Create and Update methods for your nested seralizers as DRF does not handle this.You can right your own create method for ImageSerialzier as follows:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    labels = LabelSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['id', 'file', 'labels']

    def create(self, validated_data):
       labels_data = validated_data.pop('labels')
       labels = Label.objects.create(**validated_data)
       Image.objects.create(labels=labels, **labels_data)
       return labels
```